# Checking distribution of raster layer using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-statistics, normalize

I am using ArcGIS Desktop.

How do I see if my layer has a normal distribution in order to standardize it?

I have calculated statistics, but have not been able to see how my data is distributed.

Comment: did you look at it? it probably isn't anyway

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach using Python's [Rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [Scipy](https://www.scipy.org/). In ArcGIS, you can use [`RasterToNumPyArray`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/rastertonumpyarray-function.htm) to convert your raster data to a numpy array, which you can further analyze with Scipy. You can see from the histogram that that none of the bands in this 4 band image are normally distributed. In fact this is very common with remotely sensed data. To further test to see if the bands follow a normal distribution use [`scipy.stats.normaltest`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.normaltest.html#scipy-stats-normaltest) in Scipy (see code below)

[image]

[image]

---

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show_hist
from scipy import stats

# Open GeoTIFF
src = rasterio.open("/path/to/myimage.tif")

# Plot histogram to visualize distribution
show_hist(
    src, bins=50, lw=0.0, stacked=False, alpha=0.3,
    histtype='stepfilled', title="Histogram")

# Now read band arrays for stats
b1 = src.read(1).flatten()
b2 = src.read(2).flatten()
b3 = src.read(3).flatten()
b4 = src.read(4).flatten()

def norm_test(band):
    k2, p = stats.normaltest(band)
    return k2, p

count = 1 # To get the band number
for band in [b1,b2,b3,b4]:
    alpha = 1e-3 # Alpha value 0.001 alpha value for hypothesis test
    p_value = norm_test(band)[1]
    if p_value < alpha:  # null hypothesis: x comes from a normal distribution
        print("The null hypothesis can be rejected for {0}".format("band {0}".format(count)))
    else:
        print("The null hypothesis cannot be rejected for {0}".format("band {0}".format(count)))
    count += 1
```

---

**Output:**

```
The null hypothesis can be rejected for band 1
The null hypothesis can be rejected for band 2
The null hypothesis can be rejected for band 3
The null hypothesis can be rejected for band 4
```